# Django ORM to add data into existing JSONb filed.

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

I already have data into my database as follows

```
id   |    updation_track
-----|-------------------------------
1    |   {'date1':'piyush','date2':'rakesh'}
     |
2    |   {'date1':'Neha'}
```

I want to add in updation track using django orm

```
models.objects.filter(id=1).add('updation_track':{'date3':'Rahul'})
```

I know this is wrong query , But I want to achieve something like this so that my output should be as follows:

```
 id  |    updation_track
-----|-------------------------------
1    |   {'date1':'piyush','date2':'rakesh','date3':'Rahul'}
     |
2    |   {'date1':'Neha'}
```

I am using django 1.9 and postgres version 9.4.
Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that there is a one liner like update() since you need to retrieve and modify, but the below should do it.

```
for obj in models.objects.filter(id=1).all(): 
    # assuming a more complicated filer in reality or just use get()
    obj.updation_track['date3'] = 'Rahul'
    obj.save()
```

There is some raw 'sql' to do this but I don't think the orm has a way of generating it.

Comment: How is it failing?

Comment: nephlm it's saying TypeError: 'models' object is not iterable

Comment: Whoops.  forgot the ``all()``.

Answer (score 0):

Is 'updation_track' a JSON field? If so, you may want to check [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) on JSON fields.

For updating such fields, I have not tried it but my wild guess is :

```
models.objects.filter(id=1).update(updation_track = reduce(lambda x,y: dict(x, **y), (F('updation_track'), {'date3':'Rahul'})))
```

Since JSON fields act like dictionaries in python, this would work, hopefully.

Comment: Mehmet Sencer  got error as SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression